# ASP.NET MVC - IE 11 issues on Windows 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I just created and published a new asp.net site (ASP.NET Web Application) and with google chrome the site looks and functions correct. How ever in IE 11 the layout is messed up and there is no menus. I am using windows 2012 IIS for hosting. Is there a know problem with this and how can I fix it?

Thanks
EB

Comment: Try to verify the compatiblity of your js plugins / libraries with IE 11

Comment: When I test in Internet Explorer 11 with IIS express on my local PC via Visual Studio it displays fine. I do not see the same issues as I am when I publish it?